# Please can anyone convert this query into drupal insert query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal, insert

```
INSERT INTO ip_ranges (ip, TYPE)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '12.13.14.15','blacklist') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT ip FROM ip_ranges WHERE ip = '12.13.14.15'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your Drupal Version. This is for Drupal 7:

```
<?php
$query = db_query('INSERT INTO ip_ranges (ip, TYPE) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '12.13.14.15','blacklist') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ip FROM ip_ranges WHERE ip = '12.13.14.15') LIMIT 1;');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly enhanced answer from @kwoxer (notice the {} around table names):

```
<?php
$query = db_query('INSERT INTO {ip_ranges} (ip, TYPE) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '12.13.14.15','blacklist') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ip FROM {ip_ranges} WHERE ip = '12.13.14.15') LIMIT 1;');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ip` is the `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` key, then simply

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ip_ranges (ip, `type`)
    VALUES
    ('12.13.14.15','blacklist')
```

If the above is true *and* you want to either insert or change the type to "blacklist", then do

```
INSERT INTO ip_ranges (ip, `type`)
    VALUES
    ('12.13.14.15','blacklist')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        `type` = VALUES(`type`)
```

If `ip` is not the primary key, then I don't understand your schema.